# Case Condition for two lines

Tags: equations, cases

I am searching for a way to write the case condition `$\text{in } \Omega$` in the middle of the first and second line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtool}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol\varepsilon(u) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla u + \nabla u^T \right) & \text{in } \boldsymbol\Omega \\
\mathrm{div}\,\boldsymbol \sigma + f = 0 \\
 u = \overline{u} & \text{on } \partial \boldsymbol\Omega_D \\
\boldsymbol \sigma n = \overline{ t} & \text{on } \partial \boldsymbol\Omega_N 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, we do not know how `\bold` might be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? B.t.w., `\bold` is not defined. I replaced it with `\bm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}
\newcommand{\Leg}[3][]{\left(\frac{#2}{#3}\right)_{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{div}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol\varepsilon(\bm{u}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla \bm{u} + \nabla \bm{u}^T \right) & \smash{\raisebox{-1.6ex}{in $\boldsymbol\Omega$}} \\
\divg\boldsymbol \sigma + \bm{f} = \mathbf{0} \\
\bm{u} = \overline{\bm{u}} & \text{on } \partial \boldsymbol\Omega_D \\
\boldsymbol \sigma \bm{n}= \overline{\bm{t}} & \text{on } \partial \boldsymbol\Omega_N
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
     \[ \Leg{\pi}{θ}\quad \Leg{\pi}{θ} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The main trick is using `aligned`; however, there are other improvements to your code:

1. “div” is an operator and it's much better to define a macro for it; since `\div` is preempted, I used the name `\divop`;
2. if an operator immediately follows `&` in `align` or `aligned`, it should be preceded by `\!` or a spurious thin space would be added; a little nuisance, but it's much better than `\mathrm{div}\,`;
3. `\boldsymbol` works, but `\bm` is better; remember to load `bm` after `amsmath`; you might keep `\boldsymbol`, but `\bm` is easier;
4. `\bold` is not predefined; probably you meant `\mathbf`; I recommend using `\mathbf{u}` and `\bm{\sigma}` rather than `\mathbf u` and `\bm \sigma`: it's semantically sounder;
5. `\overline` is less appealing than `\bar` for a single letter;
6. `\tfrac` is better in the context, because `\frac` in `aligned` would print a big fraction;
7. `\left` and `\right` in that context are useless: they add unwanted space and produce oversized parentheses.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareMathOperator{\divop}{div}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
&\bm{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{u}) = \tfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \mathbf{u} + \nabla \mathbf{u}^T ) \\
&\!\divop\bm{\sigma} + \mathbf{f} = \mathbf{0}
\end{aligned}&\text{in } \bm{\Omega}
\\
\mathbf{u} = \bar{\mathbf{u}} & \text{on } \partial \bm{\Omega}_D \\
\bm{\sigma} \mathbf{n} = \bar{\mathbf{t}} & \text{on } \partial \bm{\Omega}_N
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only thing I'm not happy with: `cases` uses an `\arraystretch` of `1.2`, which is consistently ignored by `aligned`. Even redefining it within the `aligned` environment does not work. Sadly, I'm fussy enough to find the non uniform line spacing irritating `:-)`

Comment: @campa I find that this spacing is better, so as to group the first two lines.

Comment: I am very sorry for the mistakes and thankful for your suggestions!